# Xamarin Native ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to call native UI into Xamarin.Forms project.

The project is still a Xamarin.Forms project, but page should be created by using Android Native Code.

Which means, it should have an empty Xamarin.Forms pages, and then write every element in Android, and display them in the page view rendered.

Can anybody tell me is this possible in Xamarin.Froms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Xamarin Forms has a concept of [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) which do exactly what you describe.  You define a custom control in Forms, and then for each platform provide a native implementation of that control using the platforms' native UI controls.